# csv is converting numbers in excel to date or text instead of numbers

Tags: excel, csv, format

I am automatically generating csv from the SQL server.

Some users have problem that excel automatically converts some numbers to date.
If the value is not converted to date, then it is formated as txt.

When I open the file it is shown ok = without text or date = just as number..

Dont you know how it can be fixed?

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: A bit more info would be useful. For starters, have you looked at _how_ your users are opening the csv in Excel and compared that with the method you use?

Answer (score 0):

Select the single column you want to convert -> Data-> Text To Columns 
In the Text to Column Wizard hit Delimited and Next -> Next
In the Column data Format section select "General" press Finish.

This will convert text to numeric values.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

the problem lied in a regional settings.

Comment: If this solved your problem please consider providing more detail about how you fixed and accepting this as the answer once you are able to do so.